# If i reject a relic, can i get it offered again in the same run?

Tags: slay-the-spire

For some tactical reasons it could be wise to reject a relic offered as reward (e.g. Dead branch, bottled relics,...).

I wonder, if i get offered the relic and reject it after a elite fight, is there a chance that i get the relic offered again after another elite fight in the same run?

In that case it would be wise to get every relic to avoid missing a better relic after later elite fight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will you get offered the same relic immediately after refusing?

**No**. I can confirm that.

> Is it possible to randomly re-encounter a refused relic during the same run?

**Probably not**.

Games like Slay the Spire (e.g. the Binding of Isaac is a good second example here) work based off of a **seeded** random number generator. The number seed (i.e. the sequence of randomized dice rolls) is often decided *before* the player begins the game, and thus the chosen random option (relics, map layout, ...) are all fixed from that point on. Therefore, all of the relics you will encounter will already be assigned before you've even been able to accept/refuse the relic the first time.

There are exceptions to this (e.g. RPG games are more likely to generate random loot when you open the chest, rather than when you create your character), but that's often due to considerations of dozens of hours of gameplay, you can't generate every option.
Slay the Spire is much simpler and can effectively decide every choice before you start playing, and it's often done (specifically so you can share a seed with others so they can play the exact same game as you).

Comment: That sounds very reasonable. Could have thought about the seed myself, thank you for your answer

Comment: The seed could easily only randomize the order of relics, not their location

Comment: @npst The map generation also has to be part of the seed. There is no way to alter the order of relics you encounter, as the relic encounters are defined by the map. If that were to be left to unseeded RNG, the whole point of sharing a seed with others becones defunct. The sinple proof here is that the daily runs are clearly identical for all players.

Comment: I noticed when playing on my slow computer, a longer pause after each act. I would assume it is used to generate the next act - thus it could be possible that the rejected relic can be found again in the next act. Very thin evidence, but still ...

Comment: @StampedeXV Is it possible to get the same relic twice? As I understand it, the map and relic locations are determined only by the seed and not player actions. If it's possible to skip a relic and then pick it up later, it'd be possible to pick it up twice, since the fact you skipped it won't affect its location.

Comment: I have not observed this nor do I imagine it is possible nor intended.

Comment: With a seeded RNG like in StS, you only get the same results "for stuff" if you do exactly the same things. E.g. if you restart a fight, if you play cards in different order, some random elements later will be different. That is not to say that relics aint't fixed at the start based of the seed, it's just that the seeded RNG is a red herring here, IMO.